# how to use onCellSelect method in JqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

```
 onCellSelect : function(rowid, iCol, cellcontent) {
      $('#caseHistoryGrid').dialog('close');
      $('#Case_Id').val(jQuery("#case").jqGrid('getCell', rowid,'caseId'));
      $('#visitId').val(jQuery("#case").jqGrid('getCell', rowid,'visitId'));
      alert($('#visitId').val()
    );
  }
```

when i click any cell. i get First VisitID only.
what s my Fault.
Please help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you should post more details. How jqGrid are defined (especially `colModel`)? What is controls `#Case_Id`, `'#visitId'` and the dialog `#caseHistoryGrid`? Do you use and editing mode and do you try to read the content from the cells which are in the editing mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in This Code Not Problem But i get data from database using Ajax in tese data is formate 

id

.....
 
give id is Not Unique So it gives the same celll

Comment: I recommend you to use `idPrefix` option to be sure that you have unique ids in grid.

Comment: @Oleg how to use idPrefix?Demo Please

Comment: the usage of `idPrefix` is very easy: `idPrefix: "someText"`. For example, `idPrefix: "x_"` will produce `id="x_1"` instead of `id="1"` for the rowsid `1`. In [the search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+%5Bjqgrid%5D+idPrefix) you will find different examples of the usage of `idPrefix`.